# Handling UIActivityViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, sprite-kit

First I couldn't find anyone else having this problem. Working on a game in spritekit - there is a mainTitle.h/m and gamePlay.h/m files. Below is code for the share button to share your progress via text, fb, twitter, ect. The code below is located in the gamePlay.m inside a touch method. The code works however after the user selects to send his/her score view text message - the new message window slides up and then the game appears to restart and load mainTitle.m scene. Any ideas as to why this happens?

```
-(void)share {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
  [self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.boundsafterScreenUpdates:YES];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"messge"];
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat@"www..."];
  NSURL *gmURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

  UIActivityViewController *actVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
  initWithActivityItems:@[message, gmURL, image] applicationActivites:nil];
  actVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeAriDrop];

  UIViewController *viewControl = self.view.window.rootViewController;
  [viewControl presentViewController:actVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)touchBegins ... {
    [self share];
}
```

Comment: touchBegins is your custom method or its a short of - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{} ?

Comment: the touch method is just a short of -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}. I figured the problem is in the share method. Not sure whats going wrong bug possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably its not a good idea to call share method in touchBegan, since it might be fired multiple times in some conditions. Use i.e. UIButton instead

Comment: Tried it both ways (UIButton, and in Touch method) still same problem. Second calling the method multiple times would only bring up the Activity menu - The user must select an activity after and thats where the problem is. The moment the user chooses to share via text message - when the new message window pops up it appears to restart the app or cycle back to the Title scene.

Comment: whats the parent class of your gamePlay.{h,m} ?

Comment: gamePlay.m is the parent

Comment: look at gamePlay.h, here should be something like: @interface gamePlay : ParentClass

Comment: gamePlay.m:SKScene is the parent*